# Error Parsing Data: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json, recaptcha, cloudflare

The URL that I use to get JSON from redirects the URL to recaptcha and gives the following error: "data org.json.JSONException: Value `<!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`"

Following is the activity and the code has the url i am trying to get JSON from but instead i get redirected to recaptcha:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
//URL

                jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                        .getJSONfromURL("http://laboneinside.com/android/diag_conn.php");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("result");
                Log.i("JSON TAG", jsonobject.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("nameDiag", jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    map.put("srcDiag", jsonobject.getString("src"));
                    map.put("linkDiag", jsonobject.getString("link"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

JSONFUNCTION:

```
public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.i("JSON Parser", result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

Following is the logcat:

```
I/JSON Parser: <!DOCTYPE html>
                                                                          <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
                                                                          <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
                                                                          <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
                                                                          <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
                                                                          <head>
                                                                          <title>Attention Required! | CloudFlare</title>
                                                                          <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                                                                          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                                                                          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
                                                                          <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
                                                                          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
                                                                          <link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
                                                                          <!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
                                                                          <style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>
                                                                          <!--[if lte IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
                                                                          <!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/zepto.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
                                                                          <script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.common.js"></script>


                                                                          </head>
                                                                          <body>
                                                                            <div id="cf-wrapper">
                                                                              <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
                                                                              <div id="cf-error-details" class="cf-error-details-wrapper">
                                                                                <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
                                                                                  <h1 data-translate="challenge_headline">One more step</h1>
                                                                                  <h2 class="cf-subheadline"><span data-translate="complete_sec_check">Please complete the security check to access</span> laboneinside.com</h2>
                                                                                </div><!-- /.header -->

                                                                                <div class="cf-section cf-highlight cf-captcha-container">
                                                                                  <div class="cf-wrapper">
                                                                                    <div class="cf-columns two">
                                                                                      <div class="cf-column">
                                                                                        <div class="cf-highlight-inverse cf-form-stacked">
                                                                                          <form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_captcha" method="get">
                                                                            <script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.challenge.js" data-type="normal"  data-ray="308cf17ac17329be" async data-sitekey="6LfOYgoTAAAAAInWDVTLSc8Yibqp-c9DaLimzNGM" data-stoken="kvvwvLSUth2MQ7fsfXFwr9TjwkJ6pEiMAfiAhb7x9fVk7yqCvGMh-myXoKQuhQt_4MjgZHunito0fikCnHS-DFoymBKWm5gb3lnlB4dceb0"></script>
                                                                            <div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
                                                                            <noscript id="cf-captcha-bookmark" class="cf-captcha-info">
                                                                              <div><div style="width: 302px">
                                                                                <div>
                                                                                  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6LfOYgoTAAAAAInWDVTLSc8Yibqp-c9DaLimzNGM&stoken=kvvwvLSUth2MQ7fsfXFwr9TjwkJ6pEiMAfiAhb7x9fVk7yqCvGMh-myXoKQuhQt_4MjgZHunito0fikCnHS-DFoymBKWm5gb3lnlB4dceb0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 302px; height:422px; border-style: none;"></iframe>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <div style="width: 300px; border-style: none; bottom: 12px; left: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; right: 25px; background: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; border-radius: 3px;">
                                                                                  <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;"></textarea>
                                                                                  <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                              </div></div>
                                                                            </noscript>
                                                                          </form>

                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                      </div>

                                                                                      <div class="cf-column">
                                                                                        <div class="cf-screenshot-container">

                                                                                          <span class="cf-no-screenshot"></span>

                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                      </div>
                                                                                    </div><!-- /.columns -->
                                                                                  </div>
                                                                                </div><!-- /.captcha-container -->

                                                                                <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
                                                                                  <div class="cf-columns two">
                                                                                    <div class="cf-column">
                                                                                      <h2 data-translate="why_captcha_headline">Why do I have to complete a CAP
11-28 04:55:15.976 30265-30325/com.example.predator.labone E/log_tag: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

How do i stop it from redirecting so that i can get to the page that has the JSON data?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to convert String into JSON Object that's why you are getting this error.Before converting the response as JSON Object make sure that response is in JSON From.

Comment: See the Question again i have edited it @Vishwa

Comment: can you post this functionality code .. JSONfunctions
                        .getJSONfromURL()

Comment: See my answer, hope it helps

Comment: @Vishwa I have posted the functions code

Answer (score 1):

There is some type of firewall applied to the network that you are using, 
Please read the HTML carefully, "`Please complete the security check to access`"

I tried hitting the url mentioned and it gives following response,

```
{"result":[{"id":"1","name":"Acer V3-571 Schematic Diagram","src":"https:\/\/www.laboneinside.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/11\/Acer-V3-571-Schematic-Diagram-620x330.png","link":"https:\/\/www.laboneinside.com\/acer-v3-571-schematic-diagram\/"}]}
```

Try using some other network/WIFI or fix the old one.

Comment: If i am getting this error on my network someone else can too so changing the network is not the solution

Comment: My main concern is your network has some firewall which your server can't pass. Like normally parents restrict facebook server so there child can't use facebook at home network, So in that case you can't blame facebook for there code. Try to understand

Comment: @NelsonJohn  Sahil Garg is right.When i tried with your code it's working.give a try with some other network connection.

Answer (score 0):

Nelson you are getting html content from web service. Response format is not a valid json that by JSONException occur.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a captcha is to prevent screen scraping and bot attacks. Based on what you are facing, Cloudflare understands that your call is a bot and is redirecting it automatically to the captcha page. Ask the API provider to remove bot protection for the API using a Page Rule. For more details read this article https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200504045-Using-CloudFlare-with-your-API